# DNS A record is not working with Amazon Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a domain name from MediaTemple that I would like to point to a server EC2 instance on AWS. On my registrar's web site I specified AWS name servers. Using Route 53 I created specified DNS record (NS, A, SOA). I waited > 24 hours for changes to propagate but I can't access my website via my domain name.

Checking my records using a site https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/mywebsitehere.com  I see that my A records are failing. The NS records look fine.

I have an A record defined in hosted zone.  Not sure where to go from here.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have an `A` record for `example.com`. You have an `A` record for `*.example.com`, in which `example.com` is not included. You will need two records.

Comment: facepalm. thank you. for some reason i thought that *.example.com includes example.com...